# How to send a List<object> to a Web Method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, list, object, asmx

I am developing a web application using MVC 3 and ASMX Web Services.

I am trying to send a List< object > to a Web Method, but I get the following error:

" cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'WebServiceClass.ArrayOfAnyType' "

This is my Web Service definition:

```
public class WebServiceClass : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public bool MyWebMethod(List<object> ParameterValues)
    {
        //do stuff..
    }
}
```

And this is the block of code where I call the Web Method:

```
        List<object> ParameterValues = new List<object>();

        WebServiceClass.WebServiceClassSoapClient MyWebService = new WebServiceClass.WebServiceClassSoapClient();

        //I use actual objects here, this is just for an example
        ParameterValues.Add(new DateTime(2012,5,2));
        ParameterValues.Add(23);
        ParameterValues.Add("some string");

        MyWebService.MyWebMethod(ParameterValues);
```

My idea was to save time and pass Lists of objects to all Web Methods instead of defining WebMethod(DateTime date, int someint, string somestring).

Is there a solution for this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method expects 3 parameters of type `DateTime`, `int`, and `string` than define a method with this arguments. Otherwise you will have to case down and your solution is not type-safe.

Are all your methods in code taking a list of objects as a parameter? Probably not. And the same should apply to web methods.

Comment: I want all my web methods to receive a list of objects because all of them call stored procedures with a lot parameters. My idea is to then iterate the list with a `foreach` and add all parameters to the stored procedure command effortlessly. I thought about an alternative, which is to have the List< object > on the web service side and then call a web method that adds a single object to the list. The problem is that when I call the web method, a new instance of the web service is created and I lose what was previously inside the list.